# is there a function to create new variable based on one condition if any of my 27 columns have "Yes", then create 1, otherwise 0

Tags: r

Hi I got dataframe about 28 columns and each columns contains Yes, No or NA. I would like to create new variable, if any of the columns contains "Yes", then create 1, otherwise 0.

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example? You don't need to produce all 27 columns, but something like it.

Answer (score 4):

We can create a new column by getting the `rowSums` of logical matrix (`df1 == "Yes"`) and check if it is greater than 0

```
df1$newVar <- as.integer(rowSums(df1 == "Yes", na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```